# Compare Excel cells Python

Tags: python, excel

I would like to compare two parts of two different columns from an Excel file that have a different number of elements. The comparison should be made between a part of Column 3 and a part of Column 2. Column 3 part has a length of j elements and Column 2 has a length of k elements(k>j). Column 2 part starts from row "j+1" and column 3 part starts from row 1. If an element from column 3 part is matching an element from column 2 part, then should check if the element from column1, before the j row, which has the same index as matched item from column 3 part is matching with the element from Column 1 part between j+1 and k, which has the same index as matched item from column 2 part. If yes, then should be written the element from Column 4 with the same index as matched element from column 2 part in a new Excel sheet.

Example: `Column3[1]==Column2[2]`(which represents element 'A') => `Column1[1]==Column1[j+2]`(which represents element 'P') => `Column4[j+2]` should be written in a new sheet.

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4
  P         F        A          S
  B         G        X          T
  C         H        K          V
  D         I        M          W
  P         B        R          B
  P         A        R          D
  C         D        H          E
  D         E        J          k
  E         M        K          W
  F         F        L          Q
  Q         F        K          Q
```

For reading the Excel sheet cells from original sheet, I have used the `df27.ix[:j-1,1]`.

One part of the code which reads the values of the mention part from column 3 and column 2 might be:

```
for j in range(1,j):
        c3=sheet['B'+str(j)].value
        for k in range(j,j+k):
                c2=sheet['B'+str(k)].value
```

Any hint how I can accomplish this?

**UPDATED**

I have tried a new code which takes in consideration that we have '-', like joaquin mentioned in his example.

Joaquin's example:

```
   C1  C2  C3  C4
0   P   -   A   -
1   B   -   X   -
2   C   -   K   -
3   D   -   M   -
4   P   B   -   B
5   P   A   -   D
6   C   D   -   E
7   D   E   -   k
8   E   M   -   W
9   F   F   -   Q
10  Q   F   -   Q
```

New code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('/media/sf_vboxshared/x.xlsx')
sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
C13=[]
C12=[]
C1=[]
C2=[]
C3=[]
for s in range(2, sheet.max_row+1):
        C1second=sheet['A'+str(s)].value
        C2second=sheet['B'+str(s)].value
        C3second=sheet['C'+str(s)].value
        C1.append(C1second)
        C2.append(C2second)
        C3.append(C3second)
        C1=[x.encode('UTF8') for x in C1]
for y in C2:
        if y is not None:
                C2=[x.encode('UTF8') if x is not None else None for x in C2]
for z in C3:
        if z is not None:
                C3=[x.encode('UTF8') if x is not None else None for x in C3]
for x in C1:
        C13.append(x)
for x in C3:
        C13.append(x)
for x in C1:
        C12.append(x)
for x in C2:
        C12.append(x)
tosave = pd.DataFrame()
df[C13]=pd.DataFrame(C13)
df[C12]=pd.DataFrame(C12)
for item in df[C13]:
    if '-' in item: continue
    new = df[df[C12] == item]
    tosave = tosave.append(new)
```

But I still get the following error: `df[C13]=pd.DataFrame(C13) TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment`. Any idea what is wrong?

Many thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: [This](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/) might help

Comment: You only need to find pairs (c1, c3) which are  identical to pairs (c1,c2). In this case only the pair ('P', 'A') fits the condition.

Comment: just read your excel file with pandas: `df = p.read_excel(yourfilepath)` and start from there. First: READ THE DOCS

Answer (score 0):

Given your df is

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4
0   P   -   A   -
1   B   -   X   -
2   C   -   K   -
3   D   -   M   -
4   P   B   -   B
5   P   A   -   D
6   C   D   -   E
7   D   E   -   k
8   E   M   -   W
9   F   F   -   Q
10  Q   F   -   Q
```

then, I combine **C1** and **C3** and **C1** and **C2**

```
df['C13'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['C1'] + x['C3'], axis=1)
df['C12'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['C1'] + x['C2'], axis=1)
```

and compare which rows have the same pair of characters in columns **C13** and **C12**, and save them in `tosave`

```
tosave = p.DataFrame()

for item in df['C13']:
    if '-' in item: continue
    new = df[df['C12'] == item]
    tosave = tosave.append(new)
```

this gives you a `tosave` dataframe with the rows matching:

```
   C1   C2  C3  C4  C13 C12
5   P   A   -   D   P-  PA
```

That can be directly saved as it is or you can save just column C4

UPDATE: If you have data on each row, then you can not use the '-' detection (or any other kind of detection based on the differences between empty and filled columns). On the other hand, if j,k are not defined (for any j and k), your problem is actually reduced to find, for each row, identical pairs below that row. In consecuence, this:

```
tosave = p.DataFrame()

for idx, item in enumerate(df['C13']):
    new = df[df['C12'] == item]
    tosave = tosave.append(new.loc[idx+1:])
```

solves the problem given your labels and data is like:

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4
0   P   F   A   S
1   B   G   X   T
2   C   H   K   V
3   D   I   M   W
4   P   B   R   B
5   P   A   R   D
6   C   D   H   E
7   D   E   J   k
8   E   M   K   W
9   F   F   L   Q
10  Q   F   K   Q
```

This code also produces the same output as before:

```
   C1   C2  C3  C4  C13 C12
5   P   A   R   D   PR  PA
```

Note this probably needs some refinenment (p.e when a row produces 2 matches, the second row with produce 1 match, and you will need to remove replicates from the final output).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your idea is nice, but we are facing two problems. First problem would be that in all columns on all rows we have some data, but I have exemplified just with the rows/columns that I am interested in. So the condition should be something like `if C2.index>j` then continue.

Comment: The second problem is that the naming of the columns is not recognized. I have used the naming in headers attribute when I have done df_to.Excel, but because I've got just zeros instead of the desired name, I had to use "columns" attribute when I was defining each df. The naming is the same, but I still cannot access the columns when I try your code. I get the following error `TypeError: ('coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, float found', u'occurred at index 15315')`.

Comment: dfs, in my case, are created by exporting some lists in some columns. At the row 15316 of each column, the lists are finishing then it starts another ones.

Comment: @dante The code in my post solves the question you made. You cannot expect an answer that takes into account conditions you do not declare. In your post you said that  "Column 3 has  j elements and Column 2 has k elements. Column 2 starts from row "j+1" and column 3 starts from row 1". This is different from "all columns on all rows have some data". If this is the case, please edit your post and clearly state the problem.

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I have managed to have the Excel file like in the previous mentioned Excel layout and I have tried your code, but I get the following error: `df[C13] = df.apply(lambda x: x['C1'] + x['C3'], axis=1) TypeError: ('coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, float found', u'occurred at index 4')`. Any idea what could cause this error?

Comment: I would say that means you have a number instead of a character at some position in the table.Note that the solution for your question with the new restrains is still more simple than before because you only need to detect those identical pairs for each line in lines below that line.

Comment: When I am trying to run your code, I get the following error: `df['C13'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['C1'] + x['C3'], axis=1)
TypeError: unbound method apply() must be called with DataFrame instance as first argument (got function instance instead)`. The same error was encountered for the previous code provided by you. I have tried an workaround which includes the code that assumes that are '-' in those spots, but I get also an error. Please check the updated question where I have inserted the new code. Anyway, I would be glad with any solution as long as it works.