# Index error matching columns from CSV

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am currently encountering one problem with one of my scripts. I am trying to achieve the following rule: if any element from C3 is matching with any element from C2(except empty cell) => check if the element from C1 which has the same index as matching element from C3 is matching with the element from C1 which has the same index as matching element from C2 => if yes, display the element from C4 which has the index as matching element from C2.

Input is an Excel sheet from where the data is extracted and it looks like this:

```
C1  C2  C3  C4
P       A   
B       X   
C       K   
D       M   
P   B       B
P   A       D
C   D       E
D   E       K
E   M       W
F   F       Q
Q   F       Q
```

C1 means column 'A', C2 means column 'B', C3 means column 'C', C4 means column 'D'. In the empty spots from columns I don't have any element there.

Code:

```
import openpyxl
import sys
C2=[None, None, None, None, 'B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'M', 'F', 'F']
C3=['A', 'X', 'K', 'M', None, None, None, None, None, None, None]    
try:
                match=[name for name in C2 if name in C3]
                match=[i for i in match if i is not None]
except:
        print("No matches")
        sys.exit(1)
C2_index=C2.index(match)
```

I have done some debugging and if am printing the match in the try section, I am getting `['A', 'M']`, which is correct. If am printing C2 after encoding, I am getting `[None, None, None, None, 'B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'M', 'F', 'F']`, which is again correct. When I am running the whole script, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test7.py", line 39, in <module>
    C2_index=C2.index(match)
ValueError: ['A', 'M'] is not in list
```

Could you please let me know why C2 is not identifying these elements?

Comment: This error is saying that the sublist ['A', 'M'] is not in another list. I think (?) you want to check if 'A' and 'M' are individually in the list.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am willing to check. I have tried also to append the results with `for name in match: match.append(name)`, but I get "No matches" after try. Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Using this to create an accessible example will help... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is this another problem than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253244/compare-excel-cells-python/48253726?noredirect=1#comment83633331_48253726) ? On that question you also showed the table above and when you got an answer you said that this actually was not the real table, that the real table had no empty cells. Please check what a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is.

Comment: @Alex: I have edited my question and made it as minimum as possible to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Joaquin that question was posted by a colleague of mine and is about a different table. I have inserted the exact input that this script will use.

Comment: No, it is not about a different table. It is exactly the same table the post started from before edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

You are searching for a list inside a list. So you're setup right now is:

```
C2 = [None, None, None, None, 'B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'M', 'F', 'F']
match = ['A', 'M']
```

Then `C2.index(match)` looks for the list ['A', 'M'] in C2. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) for more info on the `.index` method.

To get the index for each element in `match` you can use a list comprehension:

```
[C2.index(m) for m in match]
```

returns

```
[5, 8]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was searching for.

Comment: @Romain Glad it helped... Please [mark an answer as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it resolved your question. This helps us keep track of which questions are left to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Because you weren't searching for a specific item it could not find it in the list. You were actually searching for a sublist.

Try this:

```
C2_index =[]
for i in match:
  C2_index.append(C2.index(i))
```